# Setting service port with localstack

Tags: java, localstack

**Problem**

I'm trying to start the localstack container so that the SSM system is exposed on a specific port. According the the [docs I have read](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) I should be able to specify *SSM_PORT_EXTERNAL* in the environment, however; this doesn't seem to be working.

**What I've tried**

In my gradle file I tried the following:

```
test {
    // AWS Properties for tests
    systemProperty 'SSM_PORT_EXTERNAL', '22680'
    useJUnitPlatform()
    ...
}
```

In my start-up code for the container I also tried

```
        static final LocalStackContainer INSTANCE = new AwsTestContainer()
            .withServices(SSM, S3)
            .withEnv(SSM_PORT_EXTERNAL, "22680")
            .withStartupAttempts(3)
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60L));
```

*AWSTestContainer* extends *LocalStackContainer*

In both cases localstack starts up but ignores the port I specified and I get errors because the SSM client can't connect to port 22680. Looking at the logs it appears that LocalStack is still starting on the '55003' port.

> 12:22:16.526 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.CreateContainerCmdImpl@66a7cb59[name=,hostName=,domainName=,user=,attachStdin=,attachStdout=,attachStderr=,portSpecs=,tty=,stdinOpen=,stdInOnce=,env={HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localhost,SERVICES=ssm,s3,SSM_PORT_EXTERNAL=22680},cmd={},healthcheck=,argsEscaped=,entrypoint=,image=company_name.jfrog.io/localstack/localstack:latest,volumes=com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Volumes@6fc8387e,workingDir=,macAddress=,onBuild=,networkDisabled=,exposedPorts=com.github.dockerjava.api.model.ExposedPorts@10cdb47a,stopSignal=,stopTimeout=,hostConfig=HostConfig(binds=[/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw], blkioWeight=null, blkioWeightDevice=null, blkioDeviceReadBps=null, blkioDeviceWriteBps=null, blkioDeviceReadIOps=null, blkioDeviceWriteIOps=null, memorySwappiness=null, nanoCPUs=null, capAdd=null, capDrop=null, containerIDFile=null, cpuPeriod=null, cpuRealtimePeriod=null, cpuRealtimeRuntime=null, cpuShares=null, cpuQuota=null, cpusetCpus=null, cpusetMems=null, devices=null, deviceCgroupRules=null, deviceRequests=null, diskQuota=null, dns=null, dnsOptions=null, dnsSearch=null, extraHosts=[], groupAdd=null, ipcMode=null, cgroup=null, links=[], logConfig=LogConfig(type=null, config=null), lxcConf=null, memory=null, memorySwap=null, memoryReservation=null, kernelMemory=null, networkMode=null, oomKillDisable=null, init=null, autoRemove=null, oomScoreAdj=null, portBindings={}, privileged=null, publishAllPorts=true, readonlyRootfs=null, restartPolicy=null, ulimits=null, cpuCount=null, cpuPercent=null, ioMaximumIOps=null, ioMaximumBandwidth=null, volumesFrom=[], mounts=null, pidMode=null, isolation=null, securityOpts=null, storageOpt=null, cgroupParent=null, volumeDriver=null, shmSize=null, pidsLimit=null, runtime=null, tmpFs=null, utSMode=null, usernsMode=null, sysctls=null, consoleSize=null),labels={org.testcontainers=true, org.testcontainers.sessionId=6c80eb4d-594d-49e1-9a81-2a933aa5d8e4},shell=,networkingConfig=,ipv4Address=,ipv6Address=,aliases=,authConfig=AuthConfig(username=myemail@service.com, email=null, registryAddress=company_name.jfrog.io, stackOrchestrator=null)]

**Versions**

Spring Boot: 2.4.1 using JUnit 5

LocalStack: *latest* (DEFAULT_TAG is '0.11.2' in LocalStackContainer.java)

IntelliJ: 2020.3

Gradle: 6.7.1

> ---
>
> ```
>                     Gradle 6.7.1
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Build time:   2020-11-16 17:09:24
> UTC Revision: 2972ff02f3210d2ceed2f1ea880f026acfbab5c0
>
> Kotlin:       1.3.72
>
> Groovy:       2.5.12
>
> Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
>
> JVM:          15.0.1 (AdoptOpenJDK 15.0.1+9)
>
> OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.7 x86_64

Answer (score -1):

For localstack, we need to also set environment variables for specifying where to start services.
Like in docker, we use yaml config.
For spring boot: try something like

```
.withEnv("DEFAULT_REGION","eu-central-1")
  .withEnv("EDGE_PORT","4576")
  .withEnv("SQS_PORT_EXTERNAL","4576")
  .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.SQS);
```

Comment: Doesn't work still starts up with random external port